# Convertir objeto JSON con objetos anidados en array

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo convertir en un array un objeto JSON que a su vez tiene objetos anidados?

Partiendo de:

```
{
    "title": "Fooz - Mayer",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum",
    "featured": false,
    "image": {
        "src": "https://placekitten.com/g/404/404",
        "alt": "alt for product image",
        "title": "product image",
    }
}
```

> **Editado**

Resultado esperado:

```
[
    title: "Foer",
    description: "Lorem ipsum",
    featured: false,
    image: [
       alt: "alt for product image",
       src: "https://placekitten.com/g/406/406",
       title: "product image"
    ]
]
```

Comment: dentro de image puede tener otro objeto?

Comment: lo quieres guardar todo en un solo array?

Comment: Solo los valores de cada clave son los que deseas almacenar en el array?

Comment: @PieroPajares para imagen debería haber otro array, no pueden quedar objetos, si las claves quedaran diferenciadas, p.e. "image_title" también me serviría.

Comment: @Aprendiz, quiero conservar las claves y los valores

Comment: Los arrays no tienen keys y values, solo contienen values, cual es la necesidad de querer conservar las keys de de un objeto en un array? mas allá de que no se pueda hacer como lo especificas, solo estarías dejando el array menos practico de la historia jaja, la respuesta de @PieroPajares parece ideal, si lo vas a utilizar para el resultado final de tu script (por alguna razón) pero existen maneras mas practicas de ofrecer un resultado final directamente trabajando con el objeto, podrías ser un poco mas ilustrativo editando la pregunta, un saludo.

Comment: @DєηyηCrawford estoy pasando datos entre componentes en React, necesitaba una estructura con datos, que se coma. En PHP es perfectamente normal usar arrays multidimensionales con claves significativas, es a lo que se traduce directamente un JSON de echo. Estoy algo confundido con las estructuras de datos de JS ahora mismo.

Comment: En Javascript los arrays multidimensionales son básicamente arrays dentro de arrays y su estructura no cambia en sintaxis por lo que no llevan keys, para eso tenemos al objeto en si. Y tranqui si no se resuelve tu duda podrías editar la pregunta, un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Bueno no detallaste mucho pero se puede hacer algo como:

```js
let obj = {
  "title": "Fooz - Mayer",
  "description": "Lorem ipsum",
  "featured": false,
  "image": {
    "src": "https://placekitten.com/g/404/404",
    "alt": "alt for product image",
    "title": "product image",
  }
};

const array = [];
Object.keys(obj).forEach((k) => {
  if (typeof obj[k] === 'object') {
    const objTmp = obj[k];
    Object.keys(obj[k]).forEach((k) => {
      array.push(`${k}: ${objTmp[k]}`)
    });
  } else {
    array.push(`${k}: ${obj[k]}`);
  }
});
console.log(array);
```

Recorremos el objeto y si en uno de sus valores del key es otro objeto volvemos a recorrer y guardamos cada ítem de ese objeto al array que quieres guardar.